# Two rectangles next to each other

Tags: reporting-services, export, powerpoint, ssrs-2016

UPDATE:

I managed to work around the issue: Using Subreports content stays on the first page, but I get an empty second page. Is there any logic to SSRS-behaviour?

---

Hi I have report which needs to export to PowerPoint and I need two rectangles to border each other in the report. It should look like this:
[image]

However in Powerpoint it gets pushed to two different pages:

[image]

Here is what I tried:

- I set border width to 0,25
- I set the Report property `ConsumeContainerWhitespace` to true
- I tried using tablix - but then I will have difficulty adding text or other elements
- I tried adding another rectangle around them

Comment: Since PowerPoint never pushes content from one slide to another on its own, you need to look at what happens before the shapes are created in PowerPoint.  In other words, this isn't really a PowerPoint question.

Comment: Check your widths/sizes. If ReportBody.Width + MARGIN.Left (.25) + MARGIN.Right (.25) > PageSize.Width then your second rectangle wonn't fit and will be pushed to a new page.

Comment: I think the issue is overlapping rectangles in SSRS. I didn't really solve it, but managed to work around the issue using subreports. This resulted in content staying on the first page, but an empty second page.